# Page with array of json object does not appear

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Good afternoon, I'm struggling with this [tutorial](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/02/12/postgresql-and-nodejs/#.WvIvZXWUuV7). 
I'm following a tutorial to connect PostgreSQL with Node.js 
Everything seems to work great, except at the time where I'm suposed to se tie list of json objects created in http://localhost:3000/api/v1/todos. When I try to access to this page, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK0k4.png) is what appears:
 In addition, I have no problem when adding  new info on PostgreSQL database with:

```
 curl --data "text=test&complete=false" http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/todos
```

I have no idea what should I do to solve this. 
Here is the app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

And the index.html

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pg = require('pg');
const path = require('path');
const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://localhost:5432/todo';

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;

router.post('/api/v1/todos', (req, res, next) => {
  const results = [];
  // Grab data from http request
  const data = {text: req.body.text, complete: false};
  // Get a Postgres client from the connection pool
  pg.connect(connectionString, (err, client, done) => {
    // Handle connection errors
    if(err) {
      done();
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({success: false, data: err});
    }
    // SQL Query > Insert Data
    client.query('INSERT INTO items(text, complete) values($1, $2)',
    [data.text, data.complete]);
    // SQL Query > Select Data
    const query = client.query('SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC');
    // Stream results back one row at a time
    query.on('row', (row) => {
      results.push(row);
    });
    // After all data is returned, close connection and return results
    query.on('end', () => {
      done();
      return res.json(results);
    });
  });
});

router.get('/api/v1/todos', (req, res, next) => {
  const results = [];
  // Get a Postgres client from the connection pool
  pg.connect(connectionString, (err, client, done) => {
    // Handle connection errors
    if(err) {
      done();
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({success: false, data: err});
    }
    // SQL Query > Select Data
    const query = client.query('SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC;');
    // Stream results back one row at a time
    query.on('row', (row) => {
      results.push(row);
    });
    // After all data is returned, close connection and return results
    query.on('end', () => {
      done();
      return res.json(results);
    });
  });
});

router.put('/api/v1/todos/:todo_id', (req, res, next) => {
  const results = [];
  // Grab data from the URL parameters
  const id = req.params.todo_id;
  // Grab data from http request
  const data = {text: req.body.text, complete: req.body.complete};
  // Get a Postgres client from the connection pool
  pg.connect(connectionString, (err, client, done) => {
    // Handle connection errors
    if(err) {
      done();
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({success: false, data: err});
    }
    // SQL Query > Update Data
    client.query('UPDATE items SET text=($1), complete=($2) WHERE id=($3)',
    [data.text, data.complete, id]);
    // SQL Query > Select Data
    const query = client.query("SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC");
    // Stream results back one row at a time
    query.on('row', (row) => {
      results.push(row);
    });
    // After all data is returned, close connection and return results
    query.on('end', function() {
      done();
      return res.json(results);
    });
  });
});

router.delete('/api/v1/todos/:todo_id', (req, res, next) => {
  const results = [];
  // Grab data from the URL parameters
  const id = req.params.todo_id;
  // Get a Postgres client from the connection pool
  pg.connect(connectionString, (err, client, done) => {
    // Handle connection errors
    if(err) {
      done();
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({success: false, data: err});
    }
    // SQL Query > Delete Data
    client.query('DELETE FROM items WHERE id=($1)', [id]);
    // SQL Query > Select Data
    var query = client.query('SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY id ASC');
    // Stream results back one row at a time
    query.on('row', (row) => {
      results.push(row);
    });
    // After all data is returned, close connection and return results
    query.on('end', () => {
      done();
      return res.json(results);
    });
  });
});
```

I apologize for my bad english, hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Can you add a `console.log` in `router.get('/api/v1/todos', (req, res, next) => {` method? And see if it prints when you hit the URL.

Comment: Im sorry, specifically, where should I add the console.log

Comment: I just want to see if the route gets called properly. So you can add it as the first line of the `router.get('/api/v1/todos', (req, res, next) => {` handler.

Comment: Oh okay, I did that and still shows me that the page is not found

Comment: Yes it will.. but did it print anything to console?